# 'to extrapolate performance' makes more sense than 'to expect performance by extrapolating scaling laws'. Is my understanding correct?

Tags: word-choice

the following is an excerpt from a lecture

> And there's almost this sort of ongoing arms race right now with different labs and different institutions sort of competing for training the largest models. And so maybe this dates back from early 2020 with a paper" Does it sound natural? should it be "And there's almost this sort of ongoing arms race right now with different labs and different institutions sort of competing for training the largest models. And so maybe this dates from early 2020 with a paper from OpenAI called "Scaling Laws for Neural Language Models," where they find that model performance follows a predictable power law, scales sort of as a power law with model size in terms of either compute, also just parameters. And so this scaling law kind of generalizes over multiple orders of magnitude. And that gives us the confidence that if we are to train very large models, we can expect performance just by extrapolating these scaling laws.

the last sentence doesn't sound reasonable, since the paper has already proposed the laws, anyone else doesn't need to extrapolate again. here is my version

> we can extrapolate performance just by applying these scaling laws

or simpler

> we can guess performance just by applying these scaling laws

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Another possible meaning is "we can expect [good] performance".

Comment: Just because laws apply in one situation doesn't mean they apply in all situations.

Comment: We extrapolate [a result] *from* [a set of given facts].   We don't extrapolate [a set of given facts]

Comment: Extrapolating is not a guess, it's a solid estimate or projection. I can guess you are 30, but if I know your high school graduation year, I can extrapolate you were born 18 years before that.